# How to drop down programmatically a select menu by clicking on image Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have my image property and select in template:

```
<v-img src='/logos/some.jpg'
        @click='click_select'/>

<v-select :items="currencySelect" 
        ref='select'/>
```

and in methods, I have method:

```
click_select(){
  this.$refs.select.onClick;
}
```

Clicking on image doesn't do anything and no errors logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a callback handler for that event like :

```
this.$refs.select.onClick((e) => {

  });
```

**Full example**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    currencySelect: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  },

  methods: {
    click_select() {

      this.$refs.select.onClick((e) => {

      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <button @click='click_select' class="v-btn-primary">
    select
    </button>

    <v-select :items="currencySelect" ref='select' />
  </v-app>
</div>
```