# Using button for input file in Vuejs issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use a button for the input file to trigger. But the issue I am facing here is whenever I click on the button it takes me to http://localhost:3000/availability?vue-file-input= url instead of opening the file selector. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<div class="vue-file-wrapper">
 <button class="vue-button" @click="document.getElementById('fileInput').click()">Choose&nbsp;File
 </button>
 <div>{{ filename }}</div>
 <input
   type="file"
   ref="file"
   style="display:none"
   name="vue-file-input"
   id="fileInput"
   :disabled="user.availability"
   @change="onFileSelected"
 >
</div>
```

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63125006/8172857)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Vue Refs instead of querying the DOM, this should work just fine:

```
<div class="vue-file-wrapper">
  <button class="vue-button" @click.prevent="$refs.file.click()">Choose&nbsp;File
  </button>
  <div>{{ filename }}</div>
  <input
    type="file"
    ref="file"
    style="display:none"
    name="vue-file-input"
    id="fileInput"
    :disabled="user.availability"
    @change="onFileSelected"
  />
</div>
```

This is the jsfiddle showing that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgc5rnzs

Comment: Or don't use a button at all... See e.g. https://bulma.io/documentation/form/file/ which demonstrate, that you can wrapp a input type file in a "button" that still uses the default html5 input mechanism.. :)

Comment: I have tried what you suggest above. It is still the same issue. I need to use button due to styling in our platform.

Comment: @user12763413 have you tried my answer? it should work fine.

Comment: @hammed-oyedele here is a jsfiddle with your answer, showing that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/sLmoyjv7/

Comment: Yes i did try your answer it is the same issue. Whatever I try inside name="vue-file-input" it take me to that url.

in case I type name="file-input" then it take me to 

http://localhost:3000/availability?file-input=

Comment: I have updated the answer with "click.prevent" to disable browser's default action, try it again now.